# How to determine if interface is Ethernet using ip command

Tags: shell, unix, networking, posix

When I try to determine if my selected interface is used for Ethernet using the ip command it shows `ether` under both the WiFi interface and the Ethernet interface, how do I determine which is the Ethernet interface?

I have started to write some programs to replace other bigger programs that I do not fully use and am working on writing a program to replace `nm-applet`. The program I am writing is being written in 100% UNIX shell script (not BASH, ZSH, FISH etc, but UNIX shell script). I have been able to figure out just about all of the issues I need this to solve, but am having some trouble finishing it up. So the outline for the program is as follows (I am only adding the outline so you can better understand how this program works and what it should do) anything with a `-` has been solved:

```
# Outline:

* list available network interfaces -

* ask which interface the user would like to use -

* check if the interface is for Ethernet

* check if the selected interface is up or down, if down set the interface up -

* scan for available networks -

* ask which network the user would like to use -

* check if the network is open or requires a password

* if the network is open connect, else if the network is WPA (closed) then ask for the password

* associate the interface with desired network -

* connect to the network -

* if the script is run with the -s option, then save the network information in wpa_supplicant -
```

I am working on solving `check if the interface is for Ethernet`. When I started writing this I moved from the `ifconfig` command to the `ip` command as `ip` is easier to parse and format. The issue I am having is that I need to check if the interface given by `ip` if used for `ethernet`. so to get an idea of what ip outputs I ran:

```
ip link show
```

however under both my WiFi card and my Ethernet card there is this:

`link/ether`

My question is how do I actually check if the interface is actually the ethernet interface using ip? I know how to do this using ifconfig, but can't figure it out on ip.

My current script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh

save_nwid=0

while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
    key="$1"
    case "$key" in
        -s|--save)
            save_nwid=1
            shift
            ;;
    esac
done

setup_interface() {
    # list network interfaces
    iface=$(ip link show | awk '{if (NR % 2 == 1) print $2}' | sed -e 's/://' | awk -F: '{printf "%s, ",$1 }' | sed 's/\(.*\),/\1/')

    # pick interface
    echo "interfaces found: $iface"
    echo "which interface would you like to use? "

    read -r inet

        # check if interface is Ethernet (this is not how to do it)
        ip link show "$inet" | grep "ether"

    # check if interface is up or down
    state=$(ip link show "$inet" | awk '{print $9}')

    if [ "$state" = DOWN ]; then
        sudo ip link set "$inet" up
    fi
}

scan_networks() {
    # scan for networks
    echo "scanning available networks..."
    nets=$(sudo iw $inet scan | grep 'SSID' | sort -u | awk -F: '/SSID/ {printf "%s\n",$2 }' | sed -e '/^SSID/d' -e '/^[[:space:]]*$/d')
    printf "networks found:\n%s\n" "$nets"
}

connect_network() {
    # pick SSID and SSID Password
    echo "which network would you like to connect to? "
    read -r ssid

    echo "what is the network password? "
    read -r key

    # associate the interface with desired SSID
    sudo iwconfig "$inet" essid "$ssid"

    # save connection details if -s passed
    if [ $save_nwid -eq 1 ]; then
        save_network
    fi
}

save_network() {
    sudo sh -c ' echo
    "network {
        ssid="$ssid"
        psk="$psk"
    }" ' >> /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
}

check_connection() {
    ping_cmd="ping"
    ping_url="duckduckgo.com"

    $ping_cmd -c 3 $ping_url > /dev/null
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "connection made."
    else
        echo "connection failed."
    fi
}

setup_interface
scan_networks

connect_network
check_connection
```

I was expecting ip link show to have an `Ethernet` somewhere like in ifconfig, but sadly it does not. I am unsure if the `ether` means both can be used for Ethernet, but I doubt that.

Comment: Can you use `iwconfig` instead? You can then cherry pick the ones with `"no wireless extensions"` as your Ethernet interfaces.

Comment: I am trying to do that, but the issue I am having is one I have never encountered before. I can't save it's output to a variable or parse it. For example: `iwconfig enp0s25 | grep "no wireless extensions." ` doesn't work. I need to save the output like so `check=$(iwconfig enp0s25 | grep "no wireless extensions." )` so I can do if check = X then y. I can't get it to save the output though, everytime check holds nothing even though `iwconfig enp0s25 | grep "no wireless extensions."` does output `enp0s25 no wireless extensions.`